# how to force error when fileset contain files that do not match a globmapper pattern

Tags: ant

Following code demonstrate a behavior with `ant` file `copy` task  with `globmapper`.  I wanted to copy set of files.  While copying some files needed to  rename select files matching a pattern. I thought files matching pattern will be copied with new name and others with original name.

That was wrong: If the source set contains files not matching the pattern they are **silently** ignored.

```
<project name="trial" default="test" basedir=".">
    <target name="test">
        <property name="mydir" value="${java.io.tmpdir}/demo/src"/>
        <mkdir dir="${mydir}" />
        <touch file="${mydir}/abc0.txt"/>
        <touch file="${mydir}/abc1.java"/>
        <touch file="${mydir}/abc2.java"/>

        <property name="dest" value="${java.io.tmpdir}/demo/dest"/>
        <copy todir="${dest}" >
            <fileset dir="${mydir}">
                <include name="**/*.java"/>
                <include name="**/*.txt"/>
            </fileset>
            <globmapper from="*.txt" to="*.bak"/>
        </copy>
    </target>

    <target name="clean" >
        <delete dir="${java.io.tmpdir}/demo"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

Simple ant output does not indicate that some files are copied.

```
test:
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\cygwin64\tmp\demo\src
    [touch] Creating C:\cygwin64\tmp\demo\src\abc0.txt
    [touch] Creating C:\cygwin64\tmp\demo\src\abc1.java
    [touch] Creating C:\cygwin64\tmp\demo\src\abc2.java
     [copy] Copying 1 file to C:\cygwin64\tmp\demo\dest

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

Output from debug `ant -v`

```
Setting project property: mydir -> C:\cygwin64\tmp\/demo/src                                                                     
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\cygwin64\tmp\demo\src                                                                                
    [touch] Creating C:\cygwin64\tmp\demo\src\abc0.txt                                                                           
    [touch] Creating C:\cygwin64\tmp\demo\src\abc1.java                                                                          
    [touch] Creating C:\cygwin64\tmp\demo\src\abc2.java                                                                          
Setting project property: dest -> C:\cygwin64\tmp\/demo/dest                                                                     
fileset: Setup scanner in dir C:\cygwin64\tmp\demo\src with patternSet{ includes: [**/*.java, **/*.txt] excludes: [] }           
     [copy] abc0.txt added as abc0.bak doesn't exist.                                                                            
     [copy] C:\cygwin64\tmp\demo\src\abc1.java skipped - don't know how to handle it                                             
     [copy] C:\cygwin64\tmp\demo\src\abc2.java skipped - don't know how to handle it                                             
     [copy] No sources found.                                                                                                    
     [copy] Copying 1 file to C:\cygwin64\tmp\demo\dest                                                                          
     [copy] Copying C:\cygwin64\tmp\demo\src\abc0.txt to C:\cygwin64\tmp\demo\dest\abc0.bak                                      

BUILD SUCCESSFUL                                                                                                                 
Total time: 0 seconds
```

I now understand the behavior(and possible fix), but could I force ant to error out in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`<firstmatchmapper>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html#firstmatch-mapper) contains nested mappers that are applied to a file until one of the nested mappers matches...

```xml
<copy todir="${dest}" >
    <fileset dir="${mydir}">
        <include name="**/*.java"/>
        <include name="**/*.txt"/>
    </fileset>
    <firstmatchmapper>
        <globmapper from="*.txt" to="*.bak"/>
        <identitymapper/>
    </firstmatchmapper>
</copy>
```

## Output

```
 [copy] Copying 3 files to C:\cygwin\tmp\demo\dest
 [copy] Copying C:\cygwin\tmp\demo\src\abc0.txt to C:\cygwin\tmp\demo\dest\abc0.bak
 [copy] Copying C:\cygwin\tmp\demo\src\abc1.java to C:\cygwin\tmp\demo\dest\abc1.java
 [copy] Copying C:\cygwin\tmp\demo\src\abc2.java to C:\cygwin\tmp\demo\dest\abc2.java
```

Notice that the extension of `abc0.txt` changed to `.bak`, but the `.java` extensions of the other files were left unchanged.

## Explanation

In the above example, `<firstmatchmapper>` contains two mappers:

1. `<globmapper from="*.txt" to="*.bak"/>`
2. `<identitymapper/>`

For `abc0.txt`:

1. `abc0.txt` matches `<globmapper
   from="*.txt" ...>`, so `<globmapper
   from="*.txt" to="*.bak"/>` is applied to get `abc0.bak`.
2. Since there was already a match, `<identitymapper/>` is skipped.

For `abc1.java`:

1. `abc1.java` doesn't match `<globmapper
   from="*.txt" ...>`, so this mapper is skipped.
2. Since there hasn't been a match yet, the `<identitymapper/>` is applied.